# React Native importing React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I follow all instructions for installing React Navigation for Android.

First, "npm install --save react-navigation", " npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler". "react-native link react-native-gesture-handler" and lastly, updated my `MainActivity.java`

Here is my `MainActivity.java`:

```java
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

/**
 * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
 * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
 */
@Override
protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "InstagramClone";
}

@Override
protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
  @Override
  protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
   return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this)
  }
};
}
}
```

This is the error I got:

> - What went wrong:
>     Failed to create parent directory 'D:\React Native Projects\InstagramClone\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\build' when creating directory 'D:\React Native Projects\InstagramClone\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\build\intermediates\check-manifest\debug'

Comment: try to remove whitespaces in your directory: 'D:\React Native Projects\InstagramClone\ => 'D:\ReactNativeProjects\InstagramClone\

Comment: Did you find the solution? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

If you initiated your project with `expo` just install `react-native-gesture-handler`. But if your projected started by `react-native cli` you have to first install `react-native-gesture-handler` and then link it to all packages by the command:

```
react-native link
```

Answer (score 0):

if you had to a `link react-native-gesture-handler` there should be no problem or you try `react-native link` it will be link all package. Or if you still face same problem delete app first on your emulator then React-native run-android again

Answer (score 0):

You need to install react-native-gesture-handler npm separately. They create separated npm package for touch & gesture handling and recognition.

Step 1.

```
npm i react-native-gesture-handler
```

Step 2.

```
react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
```

Step 3.(optional )

If step 2 is not worked properly, code is not configured properly so we are manually configure it using step 3

To finalize the installation of react-native-gesture-handler for Android, be sure to make the necessary modifications to MainActivity.java:

```
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;  import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;  import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;  import
 com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity { 
@Override protected
 String getMainComponentName() { return "Example"; } 

@Override 
protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() { 
return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) { 

@Override 
protected ReactRootView createRootView() { 
return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);  } 
 }; 
 } }
```

No additional steps are required for iOS.

Please Refer the following document for more information:-

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html#installation

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gesture-handler/v/1.0.0-alpha.34?activeTab=readme

https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html